# change accordion menu to dropdown menu

Tags: html, css

I have accordion menu but when sliding it pushes the content below it down so I would like to make it drop down menu so that it will slide to the right. I could use another one but I like the styles of it. can somebody help me out, just the first `li`?

take a look here http://jsfiddle.net/RXRBm/1/ thanks for all the help.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of changing the whole thing to a new drop down menu, you could simply make the `position` of the drop down list `absolute`. I also added the functionality that the sub menu closes when the original list or the submenu is no longer hovered. [**Demo Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/RXRBm/16/)

```
/* CSS */
li {
    list-style:none;
}
ul {
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
#nav {
    float: left;
    border-top: 1px solid #999;
    border-right: 1px solid #999;
    border-left: 1px solid #999;
}
#nav li {
    position:relative;
}
#nav li a {
    width: 200px;
    text-align:center;
    display: block;
    padding: 10.7px;
    background:#ccc;
    border-top: 1px solid #eee;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #999;
    border-width:0.2px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #000;
}
#nav li a:hover, #nav li a.active {
    background: #999;
    color: #fff;
}
#nav li ul {
    display: none;
    position:absolute;
    left:221px;
    z-index:-1;
    top:-1px;
}
#nav li ul li a {
    padding: 10px;
    background:#C01F25;
    opacity:0.95;
    border-bottom: 0.1px solid red;
}

/* Changed jQuery */
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#nav > li > a").on('mouseenter', function (e) {
            if ($(this).parent().has("ul")) {
                e.preventDefault();
            }
                if (!$(this).hasClass("open")) {
                    // hide any open menus and remove all other classes
                    $("#nav li ul").slideUp(350);
                    $("#nav li a").removeClass("open");

                    // open our new menu and add the open class
                    $(this).next("ul").slideDown(350);
                    $(this).addClass("open");

                } 
    });
    $('#nav').on('mouseleave', function (e) {
        $('.open').removeClass('open').next("ul").slideUp(350)
    });
});
```

Next time you post a question you should provide your code with the question because sometimes jsFiddles are removed or the site simply crashes

Comment: nothing is changed on the demo. it is the same. I don't want it to slide down, instead to right.

Comment: thanks very much but there is one problem. when the menu slides to right and hover it, it disappears.. please fix that. when the menu slides just hover to it and you will see the prob thanks.

Comment: Updated again. Hope you're happy!

Comment: okay I will include the code next time. I have tried the above code but nothing has changed.

Comment: I got it to fully function in all modern browsers now, check the edit

Comment: @user2708382 Did I end up helping you resolving your issue?